# Accidentally URL Encoding URI Twice, Invalid Signature Response

Tags: powershell, netsuite, urlencode

I'll try to explain this best I can. I'm trying to perform a simple GET against the NetSuite "employees" API (using PowerShell). As you can see in the `$query` below, this variable needs to be URL encoded (spaces in the query) which I am doing on line 20 of the below snippet. I'm then taking that encoded URL along with a couple other variables and building the `$base_string`. I use the `$base_string` to create the Base64 OAuth signature and, on line 36, URL encode the signature. My response from NetSuite is always Invalid Signature.

When I perform any sort of "standard" query (like the one immediately below, without spaces... meaning no changes to the URL after encoding) I do not get an Invalid Signature response. This leads me to believe the problem is entirely related to the more unique query I am attempting and, possibly, the fact that it is being "double-encoded."

I'd appreciate any feedback as I would really benefit from being able to perform a query against the `custentity` variable in the below snippet.

```
$query =                  "/services/rest/record/v1/employee/$($netsuite_id)" # This query will find a user via their NetSuite ID.
```

```
$url =                    "https://$($realm.ToLower().Replace("_","-")).suitetalk.api.netsuite.com"
$query =                  "/services/rest/record/v1/employee?q=custentity_coupa_emp_id IS $($employee_id)" # This query will find a user via a custom entity --- their Coupa ID.
$oauth_nonce =            [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes([System.DateTime]::Now.Ticks.ToString()))
$oauth_timestamp =        [int64](([datetime]::UtcNow)-(Get-Date "1970-01-01")).TotalSeconds

# BUILD THE BASE STRING VARIABLE
$oAuthParamsForSigning = @{}
$oAuthParamsForSigning.Add("oauth_consumer_key",$oauth_consumer_key)
$oAuthParamsForSigning.Add("oauth_token",$oauth_token)
$oAuthParamsForSigning.Add("oauth_signature_method",$oauth_signature_method)
$oAuthParamsForSigning.Add("oauth_nonce",$oauth_nonce)
$oAuthParamsForSigning.Add("oauth_timestamp",$oauth_timestamp)
$oAuthParamsForSigning.Add("oauth_version",$oauth_version)
$oAuthParamsString = ($oAuthParamsForSigning.Keys | Sort-Object | % {
    "$_=$($oAuthParamsForSigning[$_])"
}) -join "&"
$encodedOAuthParamsString = [uri]::EscapeDataString($oAuthParamsString)

# BUILD THE ENCODED FULL URL VARIABLE
$encodedUrl = [uri]::EscapeDataString($url+$query)

# BUILD THE OAUTH SIGNATURE VARIABLE: KEY (CONSUMER SECRET + TOKEN SECRET) + BASE STRING
$base_string = $HTTP_method + "&" + $encodedUrl + "&" + $encodedOAuthParamsString
$key = $oauth_consumer_secret + "&" + $oauth_token_secret

$hmacsha256 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha256.Key = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($key)
$oauth_signature = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($hmacsha256.ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($base_string)))

# BUILD THE HEADERS VARIABLE
$authHeaderString = ($oAuthParamsForSigning.Keys | Sort-Object | % {
    "$_=`"$([uri]::EscapeDataString($oAuthParamsForSigning[$_]))`""
}) -join ","
$authHeaderString += ",realm=`"$([uri]::EscapeDataString($realm))`""
$authHeaderString += ",oauth_signature=`"$([uri]::EscapeDataString($oauth_signature))`""
$authHeaders = @{
    "Content-Type"="application/json"
    ;"Prefer"="transient"
    ;"Authorization"="OAuth $authHeaderString"
    ;"Accept"="*/*"
    ;"Cache-Control"="no-cache"
    ;"Host"="3489459-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com"
    ;"Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"
    ;"Cookie"="NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING"
}
```

Comment: For additional reference I am using NetSuite's documentation here RE: this more unique query: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_1545222128.html

Comment: Also note that this DOES work in Postman... so there is a way to do this.

Comment: What is in $base_string?

Comment: That is concatenated on line 23. The HTTP_method in this case is "GET". `$base_string = $HTTP_method + "&" + $encodedUrl + "&" + $encodedOAuthParamsString`

Answer (score 0):

I have no background with PowerShell but I've had this issue previously with Python and it's tricky without using libraries. I found out that:

- Your Base URL cannot contain `query params`. Meaning your base url should be:

  `"https://$($realm.ToLower().Replace("_","-")).suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/employee"`
- Since you're only doing `GET` request, just throw your query into a payload (JSON formatted). At least with my SuiteQL this is how I did it. Moving the query to payload worked for me.
- For `POST` Request, the parameters will need to be included in the Base String Creation, sorted alphabetically or by value if keys are the same name.

  My query for example for SuiteQL was `query = json.dumps({ q: SELECT FROM WHERE })`